# XML deserialization does not read all parameters

Tags: xml, soap, deserialization

I have this response to deserialize:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <ns2:getidspedizionebyrmaResponse xmlns:ns2="http://getidspedizionebyrma.wsbeans.iseries/">
        <return>
            <ESITO>-11</ESITO>
            <SPEDIZIONE_ID>0</SPEDIZIONE_ID>
            <VERSIONE>0</VERSIONE>
        </return>
    </ns2:getidspedizionebyrmaResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And I've written this class to do that:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class SoapEnvelope
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public Body Body { get; set; }
}

public class Body
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "getidspedizionebyrmaResponse", Namespace = "http://getidspedizionebyrma.wsbeans.iseries/")]
    public GetIdSpedizioneByRmaResponse getidspedizionebyrmaResponse { get; set; }
}

public class GetIdSpedizioneByRmaResponse
{
    public getidspedizionebyrmaResult ReturnValue { get; set; }
}

public class getidspedizionebyrmaResult
{
    public int ESITO { get; set; }
    public int SPEDIZIONE_ID { get; set; }
    public int VERSIONE { get; set; }
}
```

ReturnValue is always null. Maybe there is some problem with namespaces? Where do I go wrong? Thanks

Comment: Add above the property getidspedizionebyrmaResult : [XmlElement(ElementName = "return", Namespace = "")]
        public getidspedizionebyrmaResult ReturnValue { get; set; }